# Stuck with my query

Tags: sql, oracle

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with my query.

I need it to show the difference between max salary and salary of others.

```
select e.ename, f.sal, e.sal 
from emp e , (select max(sal) as "sal" from emp) f
where 1=1 ;
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error shows?

Comment: %s: invalid identifier

Comment: `f."sal"` eliminates ORA-00904. `where` is not needed. Better use analytic `max()`.

Comment: Please do not use commas between tables (or subqueries) in the from clause  any longer. That is an old syntax (>25 years old) which should have died long ago.  Don't learn bad habits STOP using commas i the from clause - then you will need to use better SQL Standard join syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
      name
    , sal
    , max_sal - sal as diff
from (
     select
          e.ename
        , e.sal 
        , max(salary) over() as max_sal
     from emp e
     ) d
```

I suggest using `max(salary) over()` analytic (or window) function which places the maximum salary on every row of the subquery, then it is a simple subtraction to calculate the difference. No `group by clause` is required in this form of aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.ename, 
       e.sal sal_of_others,
      (select max(sal) from emp where ename = e.ename ) - e.sal sal_diff 
  from emp e
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use where condition unnecessarily and also you can use subquery as shown below

```
SELECT e.ename, e.sal, (select max(sal) from emp) - E.Sal as difference 
FROM emp e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function to find the maximum salary - this negates the need to query the table twice:

```
select ename,
       sal,
       max(sal) over () max_overall_sal,
       max(sal) over (partition by deptno) max_sal_per_dept
from   emp;
```

I've given you two ways to find the max salary - one across the whole data set (`over ()`) and one per department (`over (partition by deptno)`) since I wasn't sure which you wanted.

If you are unfamiliar with analytic functions, I highly recommend you look them up. In their basic form, they're similar to how aggregate functions work, except instead of collapsing the rows, they report the value for each row. The `partition by` clause groups the data in the same way as the `group by` does in an aggregate query.

Comment: I will definitely look them up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the below query

```
select ename,sal,((select max(sal) from emp)-sal) as saldiff from emp
```